# onPress doesn't detect props of touchable opacity in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-native

onPress doesn't show me the id of my touchable opacity component when I press on it. He just shows me undefined.

```
    render() {
            var rows = [];
            var i = 0;
            while(i<5){
              rows.push(<TouchableOpacity id={i} activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={() => alert(this.props.id)}>
                  <View>
    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>);
              i++;
            }
        return {rows}
}
```

I want to when I press on it, it shows the id of touchable opacity. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you have for this `render()` function would need to have a prop `id` for this to show an alert, but I think you are wanting to show each value of `i`. Due to `i` never going out of scope within this function (as it is `var`), if you attempted to just do `alert(i)` it would show `5` for each button, but if you use `const` inside the `while` to store the current value of `i`, each button will have the correct value:

```
while (i < 5) {
  const temp = i;

  rows.push(
    <TouchableOpacity
      id={i}
      activeOpacity={0.9}
      onPress={() => alert(temp)}
    >
      <View />
    </TouchableOpacity>,
  );

  i++;
}
```

You can't use a prop you are assigning in another prop you are assigning like you were trying to do.

Comment: You are my hero